# Javascript: how to compare two arrays of objects and remove equal values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I have two arrays:
This is the main array(im printing it in html but the user can remove objects):

```
checkboxes = [
{name: "boxes", color: "red"},
{name: "boxes", color: "orange"},
{name: "tree", color: "green"}
{name: "tree", color: "red"}
{name: "tree", color: "yellow"}
]
```

And this is the array with the items to remove in checkboxes[]:

```
finalArray = [
{name: "tree", color: "green"}
{name: "tree", color: "red"}
{name: "tree", color: "yellow"}
]
```

The result after removing equal objects from those array must be:

```
checkboxes = [
{name: "boxes", color: "red"},
{name: "boxes", color: "orange"}
]
```

So im receiving an array (finalArray[]) with the objects to remove in the checkboxes[].
All equal objects must be removed.
I tried:
.filter and the .map but i didnt get a progress.

Thanks.

Comment: Objects like that have to be compared with your own code that works according to your own needs for what "equal" means. Normally, in JavaScript two distinct objects will never be `==` to each other, no matter what they contain.

Comment: finalArray have the objects to remove from checkboxes[]. Is like the condition. If i receive that array i have to make checkboxes only have the different objects.

Comment: The point is that every object is not equal to every other object. `{a: 1}` is not equal to another `{a: 1}` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let checkboxes = [
  {name: "boxes", color: "red"},
  {name: "boxes", color: "orange"},
  {name: "tree", color: "green"},
  {name: "tree", color: "red"},
  {name: "tree", color: "yellow"}
]
let finalArray = [
  {name: "tree", color: "green"},
  {name: "tree", color: "red"},
  {name: "tree", color: "yellow"}
]
checkboxes = checkboxes.filter(ele => !finalArray.some(finalEle => JSON.stringify(finalEle) === JSON.stringify(ele)))
console.log(checkboxes)
```

Comment: In this case that *might* work, but using `JSON.stringify()` is not reliable.

Comment: yes, other case, best answer is checked property of object

Comment: why is not reliable using JSON.stringify ? maybe i would have to have an id for trees and boxes ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({color: "red", name: "boxes"})`  and `JSON.stringify({name: "boxes", color: "red"})`

Comment: The order that the properties appear in the `.stringify()` output is not guaranteed. Like I said, it *might* work, but it might not, even if the objects appear to be equal. Also, if the objects have property values that cannot be part of JSON, then it also won't work. In general, it's not really a good way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

try using [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) and check if that element exist in finalArray using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) inside.

```js
var checkboxes = [
  { name: "boxes", color: "red" },
  { name: "boxes", color: "orange" },
  { name: "tree", color: "green" },
  { name: "tree", color: "red" },
  { name: "tree", color: "yellow" },
];

var finalArray = [
  { name: "tree", color: "green" },
  { name: "tree", color: "red" },
  { name: "tree", color: "yellow" },
];

checkboxes = checkboxes.filter(element => !finalArray.find(e => e.name === element.name && e.color === element.color));
```